# I'm quite famous nowadays, mostly because of my owner

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, anagram

I have:

> An anagram that sharpens your imagination
>   An anagram that doesn't ask for your permission
>   An anagram that is not very original
>   An anagram that is not very important

What am I?

Comment: I thought of this template, feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Are you:

> Tesla?  Elon Musk is quite prominent these days.

An anagram that sharpens your imagination

> Not sure...tales (stories)?

An anagram that don't ask for your permission

> Steal - take without permission

An anagram that is not very original

> Stale - old, out-of-date

An anagram that is not very important

> Least - about as 'not very' as you can get

Comment: Wow I was just going to post this answer ^-^ +1 I just couldn't figure out the "original" one.

Comment: Yep, you got it, too easy? :)

Comment: Oh cool!  I don't think it was too easy, and I do like the format.  I was trying to figure out the anagrams when the main answer popped into my head, so I just got lucky there!  =)

Comment: @GustavoGabriel You know, I've been trying to use your template to say I think this puzzle is 'great', but that's quite challenging.  Very nice work!

Comment: Thanks! English not being my first language, it's hard to make not too easy puzzles, glad you enjoyed it :)