# My creator is our lord and savior

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, anagram

I have:

> An anagram that can substitute buddies
>   An anagram that are formed by buddies
>   An anagram that sometimes you do on your buddy
>   An anagram that can be juicy (And maybe give to your buddy?)

What am i?

*Another one of my [riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65386/im-quite-famous-nowadays-mostly-because-of-my-owner)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am

> STEAM (created by Gabe Newell [thanks, PL457!] -- the other 4 lines are solved by anagrams of STEAM (MATES/TEAMS/TAMES [when one tames someone, that someone becomes your buddy]/MEATS)

Comment: You are almost correct with the explanation, there is one correct answer and 4 anagrams. The answer fits the title.

Comment: Just an addition: Rot13: Vg zvtug or nobhg Tnor Arjryy naq Fgrnz. Gurer vf n ehaavat wbxr orgjrra tnzref gb pnyy uvz gur ybeq naq fnivbhe bs ivqrb tnzrf.

Comment: Yep, correct now! :)